# Print correct summary() for multiple columns separated by a newline

Tags: r

I want to show multiple `summary()` tables. But the output is kind of ugly.

```
data(cars)
df = cars
for (col in c('speed', 'dist')) {

    print(cat('\n', summary(df[col])))
}
```

The output is

```
 Min.   : 4.0   1st Qu.:12.0   Median :15.0   Mean   :15.4   3rd Qu.:19.0   Max.   :25.0  NULL

 Min.   :  2.00   1st Qu.: 26.00   Median : 36.00   Mean   : 42.98   3rd Qu.: 56.00   Max.   :120.00  NULL
```

The good point with that output is that there is a new line between the "tables".
But the tables looking different from what they would look like when called one by one explict like this:

```
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    4.0    12.0    15.0    15.4    19.0    25.0 

   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   2.00   26.00   36.00   42.98   56.00  120.00
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `[[` instead of `[` to print the summary as a row, and separate `cat("\n")` into a separate call:

```
for (col in c('speed', 'dist')) {
  print(summary(df[[col]]))
  cat("\n")
}
```

```
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
4.0    12.0    15.0    15.4    19.0    25.0 

Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
2.00   26.00   36.00   42.98   56.00  120.00
```

As for why `print(cat('\n', summary(df[[col]])))` doesn't work: `summary()` returns an object with class `table` (and depending on the input, also class `summaryDefault`). As @shs noted in the comments, these classes have their own `print()` methods, yielding nicely formatted tables. However, `cat()` essentially ignores classes and attributes, and just prints the underlying vectors. As stated in [the docs](https://rdrr.io/r/base/cat.html):

> It converts its arguments to character vectors, concatenates them to a single character vector, appends the given `sep =` string(s) to each element and then outputs them. [...] Currently only atomic vectors and names are handled, together with NULL and other zero-length objects (which produce no output).

Comment: Can you explain your solution a bit more please. E.g. why not doing `print('\n')`? Why not combining this? From my perspective as a Python developer it is waste of characters. ;) And why not doing `cat(summary())`? The latter cuts the columns headline; wired.

Comment: Just try `print("\n")`. It will not parse the string into a line break. `print()` and `cat()` are just different methods to print something to console. Importantly, `print()` is an S3 method, so the output can be tailored to the class of the input.

Comment: As `cat()` an `internal` function, it will ignore the class attribute of the object returned by `summary()`. Thus, it is printed as a named vector, which is the result that you see